# Deploy Google Cloud Run to multiple regions at once

Tags: google-cloud-run

I would like to know if there is way to deploy cloud run to multiple regions at once. Currently there is only one option to specify region  like this

> gcloud run deploy --image gcr.io/shaale-one-development/testservice
> testservice --platform managed --region=us-central1"

is there a possibility to deploy to multiple regions say

> gcloud run deploy --image gcr.io/shaale-one-development/testservice
> testservice --platform managed --region=us-central1,asia-south1"

Currently I am not specifying the region in the command and then later choosing the regions. Since we have predefined regions deploying to those regions at once saves time.

Comment: As a suggestion, I would be more concerned with verifying the deployment succeeded than how fast it deployed. Consider adding tests and a rollback procedure.

Comment: I agree with you, but building the image once and deploying to multiple regions and having the confirmation one after another was what I was thinking. it can deploy to regions one after another so we get confirmation one after another. Something like this but I don't think it exists at this time

Answer (score 6):

No.

You can simply repeat the command for each region:

```bash
REGIONS=(
  "us-central1"
  "asia-south1"
)
for REGION in ${REGIONS[@]}
do
  gcloud run deploy ... -- region=${REGION}
done
```

You can run `gcloud run deploy` asynchronously using [`--async`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/run/deploy#--async) to parallelize the loop but this complicates checking for success as you'll need to iterate over the return operators.

Answer (score 1):

If you are a Terraform user, you can use [this module](https://github.com/terraform-google-modules/terraform-docs-samples/blob/main/cloud_run_service_multiple_regions/main.tf) to deploy to multiple regions. See [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/multiple-regions#terraform)